sparkxgb throws poll timeout error when I train model with 10,000 features
My train data is a Spark DataFrame. One column of the DataFrame is a sparse vector constructed using SparseVector, and the length of the sparse vector is 10000.
When I train the model, even if I sample the training set and only have 10,000 records left, I still get a poll timeout.
My pipeline like this.
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCols=ohe_cols, outputCols=index_out_cols, handleInvalid='keep')
encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCols=index_out_cols, outputCols=ohe_out_cols)
va = VectorAssembler(inputCols=va_input_cols, outputCol='features')
xgb = XGBoostClassifier(
    featuresCol='features', 
    labelCol='is_convert',
    weightCol='weight',
    objective='reg:logistic',
    evalMetric='auc',
    numRound=5,
    eta=0.1,
    maxDepth=2,
    missing=0.0,
    numWorkers=10,
    timeoutRequestWorkers=900,
    colsampleBytree=0.5
    )

pp = Pipeline(stages=[indexer, encoder, va, xgb])

Is it because sparkxgb does not support too many features?
